# Truth or fiction: Testing vitamins to take by holding them and assessing strength

Tags: micronutrients, allergy

I'm a Ph.D. candidate in molecular biology and cannot convince my indoctrinated mother and grandmother that you cannot determine whether or not you need to take a vitamin by simply holding it and assessing whether it increases or decreases the strength of your grasping arm.

The story is this: my grandmother became genuinely allergic to most foods and suffered massive immunosuppression, which led her to seek advice from Mayo Clinic, and after extensive testing finding nothing, she was sent home in critical condition eating potatoes and gluten-free flours. She tried 500 "alternative" things, and eventually claims that holding cans of vitamins or foods in her hand will strengthen her grasp if she needs to take them or weaken her grasp if she doesn't need them. She has recovered amazingly over the past few years, and now has convinced half of the extended family that this technique is true, which puts a lot of pressure on the three unbelieving M.D's or Ph.Ds in the family (myself included) to explain why this doesn't work. Their theory is that "frequency" in the vitamin or food translates to your body, which responds in kind with strength or no strength. I have never tried blinding her to what food or vitamin she was holding, as she is resistant to testing that because she might take something she doesn't need or is allergic to.

Where are they even getting this idea? I can't find any information online, and how do I explain to them? .... Or am I wrong?

Comment: Coincidence and expectations are amazingly powerful things, aren't they?  No, you're not wrong, but just as soon as you get a solid answer to this question I'm going to apply it to all the people who believe the anti-vaxxers, homeopaths, birthers, truthers, and chemtrailers.

Comment: I miss something in this: She became "genuinely allergic to most foods" and suffered "massive immunosuppression", but extensive testing in Mayo Clinic revealed nothing? So, first, who came with an idea that she had any allergy (with increased IgE antibodies?) and who and how diagnosed immunosuppression (if Mayo didn't)? The story does not include any symptoms of allergy (rash, vomiting, diarrhea) or infections (fever). There are a lot of reasons for reaction to foods (lactose/fructose intolerance, food poisoning, IBS, emotions, pretending...).